# Is there anyway to restrict users to hide and rearranging the columns in Datasheet view in access form?

Tags: ms-access, vba, datasheet

I am displaying table records in access form Datasheet view. While business users accessing that form, they are hiding and rearranging some columns for their use. So it will be hard for other users to access. I just want to know any settings are available in MS Access or can we accomplish this using any events or macro or modules??
 Waiting for your valuable response..

Answer (score 0):

How about having a sub like this:

```
Public Sub Reset_Columns()
   Me.Field1.ColumnOrder = 1
   Me.Field2.ColumnOrder = 2
   '...
   '---
   Me.Field1.ColumnWidth = 630
   Me.Field2.ColumnWidth = 675
   '...
End Sub
```

You can bind this sub to a button (labelled "Reset Columns") and you can call the sub on Form-Open.

Hope this helps, regards, W